# Can we pass a function as an argument

Tags: r, higher-order-functions

I'm using R to build a mathematical model. I want to write a function `f(a, b, g)` that takes in 3 arguments and the last one is a function. I want to know can I pass a function as an argument to another function? If this is possible, can you guys give me a simple example?

Comment: Functionals? http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functionals.html

Comment: Yes.  See the Examples section of `?optim`  and `?integrate` for some R functions that accept other functions as arguments.

Comment: This question is an absolutely valid question, is not unfocussed at all (it contains a question and example), and should not be closed. There is already one good answer, but given it's a complex topic, other answers may also offer valuable information/examples

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is certainly legitimate to pass a function as an argument to another function. Many elementary R functions do this. For example,

```
tapply(..., FUN)
```

You can check them by `?tapply`.

The thing is, you only treat the name of the function as a symbol. For example, in the toy example below:

```
foo1 <- function () print("this is function foo1!")
foo2 <- function () print("this is function foo2!")

test <- function (FUN) {
  if (!is.function(FUN)) stop("argument FUN is not a function!")
  FUN()
  }

## let's have a go!
test(FUN = foo1)
test(FUN = foo2)
```

It is also possible to pass function arguments of `foo1` or `foo2` to `test`, by using `...`. I leave this for you to have some research.

---

If you are familiar with C language, then it is not difficult to understand why this is legitimate. R is written in C (though its language syntax belongs to S language), so essentially this is achieved by using pointers to function. If case you want to learn more on this, see [How do function pointers in C work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a really simple example from [Hadley's text](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functionals.html):

```
randomise <- function(f) f(runif(1e3))

randomise(mean)
#> [1] 0.5059199
randomise(mean)
#> [1] 0.5029048
randomise(sum)
#> [1] 504.245
```